# Simple PostgreSQL plpgsql to create a new table using existing table

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to plpgsql.  I'm sure there is some really simple way to do this, but for some reason I'm having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to do this.

I'm simply trying to loop through the list of existing tables and execute 
**CREATE TABLE z_existing_table_name AS SELECT * FROM existing_table_name WITH DATA**
So far, I have this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_backup_row()
RETURNS RECORD
AS $$
DECLARE
  row RECORD;

BEGIN
  FOR row IN SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_catalog = 'my_db' and table_schema = 'public'
  LOOP
     EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE z_' || t.table_name || ' as ' || t.table_name
  END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It would be an added bonus if I can make this function re-runnable.  Something like drop table if exist then create table ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Steven,  use below procedure,

```
-- Function: create_backup_row()

-- DROP FUNCTION create_backup_row();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_backup_row()
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$

DECLARE
  v_table text;
BEGIN

FOR v_table IN
    SELECT table_name  
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_catalog = 'my_db' 
    AND table_schema = 'public'
    AND  table_name not ilike '%z_%'  -- to skip the table with z_ when we rerun it.
LOOP

   EXECUTE ' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS z_' || v_table ;
   EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE z_' || v_table || ' as SELECT * FROM ' || v_table ;

END LOOP;

return 1;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION create_backup_row()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Thanks!